Asset pricing based on stochastic inflation discounting (inflation controlled by stochastic state variable)
Suppose there is an asset that pays fixed nominal payout $\delta_t = \delta$, with a constant real discount rate $\bar{r}$ and stochastic inflation $\pi_t$. Suppose the price follows a controlled process
$$dP_t = \pi_t P_t dt$$
$$\pi_t = \pi(x_t)$$
where
$$dx_t=\mu_t dt + \sigma_t dW_t $$
This is to say, given current state $x_t$, which is stochastic in the future, current inflation $\pi_t$ is determined.
Now suppose the asset price is $Q_t$. The asset price is given by
$$Q_t = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{t}^{\infty}e^{-\bar{r} (s-t)}\times e^{-\int_{t}^{s}\pi_u\ du}\times \delta \ ds \right]$$
Also, asset holders are assumed to have a log utility, which captures the idea that they are risk averse.
What confuses me is that the future $\pi_t$ are unknown because it is controlled by some stochastic states $x_t$ in the future. As a result, in the asset pricing formula, there should be some kind of "inflation risk premium". However, in the formula I give above, I can see no such "premium/uncertainty".
Can someone tell me if I am correct or not, or help elaborate any example?

It's wrong. Risk neutral evaluation should happen using tradable inflation forwards as discount factors.
